# VideoJS not working in IE 10 or 11

Tags: video, html5-video, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, video.js

Navigating to http://www.videojs.com/ in IE 11 gives me the following error:

The video could not be loaded either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported

The same thing is happening on my site. Any idea what's up?